# Flex - Retrieve and store variables from PHP

Tags: php, spring, apache-flex, flex4, flex-mobile

**EDIT** - Looks like you cannot parse data from PHP without going through XML. Using JSON will be the best way. [Source](http://www.vipercreations.com/tutorials.php?t=28&page=3&c=Adobe%20Flex)

I'm very new to Flex been using it for 2.5 days. My Flex application accesses a PHP script that calculates two numbers. The script works as it is but I want to retrieve multiple variables from the PHP script so I can have an answer for not only addition but also multiplcation etc...

I hope I have made some sense....

**Flex:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="Adding Numbers">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="srvCalc" url="http://192.168.0.3/flex/flex-phpexample/calc.php"
                   resultFormat="text"
                   method="POST">

        <s:request xmlns="">
            <number1>{txtNumber1.text}</number1>
            <number2>{txtNumber2.text}</number2>
        </s:request>

    </s:HTTPService>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function btnCalc_Click(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                srvCalc.send();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup width="400" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:Label id="txtAnswer" text="{srvCalc.lastResult}" />

        <s:Label text="First Number:" />
        <s:TextInput id="txtNumber1"
                     width="100%"/>

        <s:Label text="Second Number:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="txtNumber2"
                     width="100%"/>

        <s:Button id="btnCalc"
                  label="Calculate"
                  click="btnCalc_Click(event)"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:View>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];

    print($number1 + $number2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to have php return a JSON encoded block and then use http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/ to decode it in flex.  There are some other methods you can use, but this is the easiest and most structured way.

Comment: I have looked, my initial idea I want to build up from this is to create a login view. So that we can send a username, password and when successful I want to return a value from the PHP code like:
$loginSuccessful = true;
$firstName = "John";
$lastName = "Doe"'

Comment: Right, so you would want something along the lines of $return = array(); $return['firstname']="John"; $return['status']=true; echo(json_encode($return));

Comment: You don't actually need to use a third party library to parse JSON in AS3 anymore. Adobe has a JSON class (with #parse() and #stringify() static methods) built right in now. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html